# Including solr field names in the search string, but not in the facet

Tags: solr, facet

I want to be able to include a field name in my search, but not show up as part of the indexed term in the search facet.

Example field name and data:

Skill:
- Poor
- Good
- Excellent

This field gets copied into the default text field and I would like a user to be able to search for 'poor skill', without having to choose the 'skill' field.

I've extended the field data so that I'm indexing:

- Poor Skill
- Good Skill
- Excellent Skill

But obviously, when I use this as a search facet, then I get 'Skill' in the return.

Is there a way to tell solr to include the field name as part of what gets indexed? Can I include extra text in a copy field? i.e it indexes 'poor'  but I can copy 'skill poor' into the main text index field.

I could blank it out on the UI front end, but this seems a little messy and I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should use two fields in your document.
One for searching and the other to display the facet.

Then apply differents filters in this two fields. The filters on the "search" field should obviously facilitate search (like ASCIIFolding). The filters on the "facet" field should pretty print your facet values (like CapitalizationFilter)

If you have to add the word "skill" to create your facet, I think you should read this doc : 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor

By creating a custom processor you will be able to add the word "skill" for the facet.

Comment: Ok, so that's more or less what I have.  So you are saying I need 3 fields really.  One which is my text field, which the faceting data gets copied into from a 'long' facet data field simply to hold it so it gets copied into text. Finally the actual field to create the facet...?  There is no way to append some data in a copyfield schema command then that you know of?